# Assesment of the sphericity with r

Tags: r

I have these data and I want to assess the sphericity as a condition to apply an ANOVA for repeated measures.

```
EGPRE<-c(4, 6, 2, 6)
EGPOST<-c(7, 3, 2, 6)
EGRE<-c(6, 2, 1, 4)
```

What test do I have to use? *Mauchly* test or maybe *Greenhouse-Geisser* test? How do I develop them with R?

Answer (score 0):

R has `mauchly.test {stats}` as part of the base stats package. You can type `help(mauchly.test)` in the R console for more details.

Which test you use is of course entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `aov_car` function in the `afex` package, that reports the Mauchly test by default to test for sphericity and also offers the Greenhouse-Geiser or Huynh-Feldt corrections for cases where sphericity isn't met.